# I cannot make WSL for Ubuntu under Windows 11 work correctly

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting this error, any hints how to fix it ?

```
$ wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04                                                 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS je již nainstalovaný.
Spouští se Ubuntu 22.04 LTS…
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
Error: 0x80370114 Operaci se nepovedlo spustit, proto?e nenÝ nainstalovanß po?adovanß funkce.

Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/wsl-2-installing-linux-failed-error-code/bae391d1-4215-4d93-b0c4-3d96404a7c74